# Writing data using batch files

Tags: batch-file

So I am using the "@echo" command to write data files in batch.

"@echo set value=%userinput%>> test2.bat"

The idea of this is to create a batch file named test2.bat that has 1 line of text which should be "set value=%userinput%" user input being what ever the user typed. The problem is that when every the users input is only a single digit such as 1, 2, 3, and so fourth, the command won't function. If I turned the 1 into a 10, then the command works but if I chose anything between 1 and 9 it just won't work the way it should. Could someone explain to me why? and recommended work around?

Answer (score 0):

```
>> test2.bat echo set value=%userinput%
```

A digit directly before a redirector redirects that device number (0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr, 3-9 undefined)

If you want *exactly* one line in your file, use `>`. `>>` appends to any existing data; `>` recreates the file.

*unless* you want the literal `%` in your file, when you should use `%%` in place of each literal `%` you are using. `%var%` evaluates `var`, `%%var%%` puts the literal `%var%` because `%` "escapes" `%`

Answer (score 0):

Due to redirection notation being in the form `1>` & `2>` your output is eating those input digits. I think that it is easier to wrap your echo command into parentheses to prevent it instead of placing the redirection notation at the start of the line.

```bat
@(echo set value=%userinput%)>>test2.bat
```

Comment: Thank you hopefully this will resolve my issue! I was actually really surprised how fast I received a clear answer. Best first time experience on a site I've had yet